# Why am i getting ' request for member ‘******’ in something not a structure or union'?

Tags: c, typedef

I'm getting the error for `p->letter = 'A'` and `p->age = '9'`. I don't know what is going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct player {
    char letter;
    int age;
};

typedef struct player *player_t;

int main (void)
{
    player_t* p;
    p = (player_t*)malloc(1 * sizeof(player_t));
    if (p == NULL)
    {
        /* EDITED by @ahmedmasud removed original printf line for language */
        printf("Unable to allocate\n");
        return 1;
    }
    p->letter = 'A';
    p->age = '9';
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: post the full error message

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc()` in C!

Comment: `1*sizeof(player_t)` is identical to `sizeof(player_t)`. Do not pollute your code.

Comment: Remove the `*` from the typedef. It should be `typedef struct player player_t`.

Comment: what's going on is that you're getting confused by your typedef

Comment: `typedef struct player *player_t;`. It's not a good idea to call something "player_t" if it's a pointer to something. Unless you come from a world were "_t" indicates that something is a pointer, this is just going to keep confusing everyone who looks at the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You typedef

> ```
> typedef struct player *player_t;
> ```

... so `player_t` is a type of pointer to `struct player`.

Then you define a variable:

> ```
> player_t* p;
> ```

`p` is a pointer to pointer to `struct player`. Remove the `*`.

Answer (score 3):

This is an example of why you shouldn’t typedef a pointer.

`player_t` is a typedef for `struct player *`.  You then define `p` as a `player *`, which means the full type of `p` is `struct player **`.  The fact that you had a pointer hidden in a typedef ended up confusing you, and it can similarly confuse others who read your code.

Remove the pointer from the typedef and it will work as expected:

```
typedef struct player player_t;
```

Answer (score 3):

As many folks have pointed out you have a problem because in using typedef you went one step too far :-). Using `typedef` to recast types is meant for increasing clarity whereas the way you're using it *decreases* clarity.

Let me first show your example with the correct approach:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct player {
    char letter;
    int age;
};

/* typedef struct player *player_t;  NOT NEEDED */

int main (void)
{
    struct player *p;

    p = malloc(sizeof(*p)); /* used *p for sizeof instead of struct player */

    if (p == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Unable to allocate memory\n");
        return 1;
    }

    p->letter = 'A';
    p->age = '9';

    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

### When to use `typedef foo_t bar_t`

When it makes things clearer, e.g. *stdint.h* does this for integers. Say, you want a 32-bit unsigned int, you would use uint32_t which is appropriately typedef'd for various architectures to give you what you expect.

### When NOT to use `typedef struct foo foo_t`

Pretty much all the time.

### When it's OK to use `typedef struct foo foo_t`

Now for the reasons behind the changes, `typedef struct foo foo_t` is discouraged except when struct foo is opaque, typically when you are writing a C API where the structure is accessed through predefined access functions that have a longer life than internal structure.

### Why use sizeof(*p) instead of sizeof(struct player) ?

In case, for some reason, you decide to change what `*p` is then all you have to do is change the declaration, and not worry that it's not going to get appropriately allocated.

Comment: `sizeof` is an operator, not a function so `sizeof *p` would just do. No need for parenthesis here.

Answer (score 1):

`player_t* p;` is not a pointer to `struct player`; it is a pointer to *a pointer* to `struct player`. Remove the `*` from the variable declaration and from the type cast before the call to `malloc` (you do not need that cast, anyway).

Answer (score 0):

Change these two lines:

```
player_t* p;
p = (player_t*) malloc(1*sizeof(player_t));
```

into:

```
player_t p;
p = (player_t) malloc(1*sizeof(struct player));
```

`p` is of type `player_t`, which is already defined as a pointer to a `player`. No need for another `*` in its definition. Also, you need to allocate the size of the original struc, not the size of the pointer (`sizeof(player_t)` is the size in bytes of a pointer, not the size of the struct `player`).

Answer (score 0):

Apart from what others pointed, Firstly typedef a `pointer` variable is not considered as good practice as hiding the `*` makes the code hard to read. Read [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Though if you want to typedef a pointer then do like below

```
typedef struct player {
    char letter;
    int age;
}player_t, *player_p; /* player_t is normal struct & player_p is pointer struct, here when someone see _p at the end of variable means it has * */
```

Next you need to allocate memory for `player_p` for e.g

```
player_p ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct player)); /* here don't take like "player_p *ptr" as player_p is already a pointer to struct */
if(ptr == NULL) {
    /* error handling @TODO */   
}
```

Later you can access structure member like

```
ptr->letter = 'A';
ptr->age = '9'; /* age is integer member, you may want to assign integer value directly like 57 instead of '9' */
```

And free the dynamically created memory by calling `free()`.

```
free(ptr);
```

Sample code

```
typedef struct player {
        char letter;
        int age;
}player_t, *player_p;
int main(void) {
        player_p ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct player));
        if(ptr == NULL) {
                /* error handling @TODO */
        }
        ptr->letter = 'A';
        ptr->age = 50;
        printf("%c .. %d \n",ptr->letter,ptr->age);
        free(ptr);
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: Woops, never mind Achal, I misread your answer (not enough coffee!)